# Integration double angle

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How should i simplify this before applying integration. Have tried the $1-\cos2x=2\sin^2x$ but am still stuck on solving it

$$\int\left(\dfrac{\cos2x}{1-\cos4x}\right)dx$$

Comment: After that you can try making the substitution $y=\sin(2x)$.

Comment: Use the half angle formula for the denominator and then the substitution suggested by ABC. Edit your post for $dx$ as Git Gud suggested.

Comment: how does the substitution method suggested by ABC works? how does the cos2x becomes sin2x

Comment: If $y=sin(2x)$ then $dy=2cos(2x)dx$ and $1-cos(4x)=2sin^2(2x)$

Comment: As suggested above, replacing x by 2x in the identity you tried gives $1-\cos 4x=2\sin^{2}2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the double angle formula $\cos 4x=1-2\sin^22x$, we have
$$ \int \frac{\cos 2x}{1-\cos 4x}dx= \int \frac{\cos 2x}{1-(1-2\sin^22x)}dx=\int \frac{\cos 2x}{2\sin^22x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin^22x}dx$$

As ABC suggested, use the substitution $y=\sin 2x$, so that $dy=(2\cos 2x)dx\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{2}=(\cos 2x)dx$.

Thus your integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin^22x}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{dy}{y^2}$$

This is a relatively simpler integral to evaluate.

Can you take it from here?