# Integration by simplification

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble with integrating the following:

$$\int \frac{\cos2x}{1-\cos4x}\mathrm{d}x$$

I have simplified it using the double angle:

$$\int \frac{1-2\sin^2x}{1-\cos4x}\mathrm{d}x$$

But i am stuck as I am not sure on how to continue on from here. Should i use the double angle formula to simplify the denominator too?

Then there is this other question, which I am not sure on how to solve.

$$\int {(2^x+3^x)}^{2}\mathrm{d}x$$

Should i just expand and multiply the terms, then use "$\int a^x\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\ln a} a^x$ "to integrate?

I am confused on whether i am taking the correct approach in solving this question.

All help and suggestions are welcomed. Thank you very much for helping me once again, guys.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/731438/99325

Comment: @derivative Thanks dude, i searched mathstack before posting, but was not able to find it. Any recommendations to search in a more efficient manner?

Comment: No idea how to search better, i only had commented on that question 2 days ago, that's why i knew it.

Comment: @derivative Alright. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the double angle on the $\cos 4x$ term, so you obtain $\cos 4x=1-2\sin^22x$, rather than using the double angle identity on $\cos 2x$.

So your integral will simplify to 
$$\int\frac{\cos 2x}{1-\cos 4x}dx=\int\frac{\cos 2x}{1-(1-2\sin^22x)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin^22x}dx$$

Then use the substitution $u=\sin 2x$, so that $du=(2\cos 2x)dx$. I'll let you take it from here.

For your second question, as you suggest, you can expand the term as follows
$$\int(2^x+3^x)^2dx=\int(2^{2x}+2(2^x3^x)+3^{2x})dx=\int(2^{2x}+(2)6^x+3^{2x})dx$$

Simplifying further we have $$\int(2^{2x}+(2)6^x+3^{2x})dx=\int4^xdx+2\int6^xdx+\int9^xdx$$
and like you said we can use "$\int a^xdx=\frac{1}{\ln a}a^x$"

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1-\cos(4x)=1-(1-2\sin^2(2x))=2 \sin^2(2x)$.